# How does neovim handle keyboard input?

Tags: neovim, user-input

In classical Vim, keyboard input is handled fairly archaically, and it's why you can't remap say <Ctrl-M> and <Enter> to different keys or commands. This is probably my biggest gripe about Vim and I've had to employ multiple workarounds over the years to get past it. I know some have proposed a rewrite to fix this, [such as this suggestion,](https://groups.google.com/g/vim_dev/c/Ym6D-kWIsyo?pli=1) but considering the time interval in question, it seems very unlikely to be fixed anytime soon, if ever.

Hence, my question. I know neovim has been rewritten to solve a lot of Vim's problems, and I was wondering if keyboard input handling is part of that list. I've searched a lot, both in google and in the docs, and can't find anything about  it.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! The NeoVim maintainers might be able to best answer this question.